# Incompatible types: Mainactivity cannot be converted to OnClickListener

Tags: android, incomplete-type

[Click here. This is link to image error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG6C3.png)

[image]

I have started with most basic calculator app that adds and subtracts two numbers.
I'm getting this incompatible error for `SetOnClickListener()`.
Before this I got an error saying "ActivityBar is deprecated", later I changed it to
AppCompactActivity and the error cleared.

I'm really new to this and have almost no clue to what the code means I just got it online.

Comment: Make sure your Activity `implements OnClickListener`.

Comment: thanks a lot sir!! it worked.

Answer (score 7):

Your Activity must be changed like this to make it work

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

     @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            //Start activity one
            break;
        case R.id.button2
            //Start activiy two
            break;
        // Do this for all buttons.
    }
}

    }
```

This would make your code work

Answer (score 4):

methods
1 . :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  View.OnClickListener {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
}
```

2 .

```
      button.setOnClickListener(setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            }
        });
```

3 .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.fab);
       btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);


    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener= new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    };

}
```

Comment: method 1 worked for me. Turns out I was missing this code > btn.setOnClickListener(this);. and just revised my code from the btnName to just public void onClick(View v) since the Button name was already declared when the Button was initialized, thx alot. ♥♥♥

Answer (score 3):

use this statement in your onCreate method

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               //what you need to do when that button is clicked
            }
        });
```

Here button is the Button object you created from the button id in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps to resolve this problem.

1.Bring the cursor on highlighted this word

2.And press alt and enter

3.And click on

Make 'MainActivity' implement 'android.view.View.OnClickListener'

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and resolved it in following way.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  protected Button delhi_University;
  protected Button indraprastha_University;
  protected Button private_University;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Transact.class);
    delhi_University  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    indraprastha_University = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    private_University = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
  //  delhi_University.setOnClickListener(MainActivity2Activity.this);

    delhi_University.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
    indraprastha_University.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    private_University.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

In case you want to use the above method then you just need to implement View.OnClickListener at the point of declaration of class. In following way:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{....}
```

Answer (score -2):

try to make your activity implement the "View.OnClickListener".
thats will help